# How to configure zabbix agent on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, agent, zabbix, appliance

I am new to Zabbix. I finally installed the appliance version on Ubuntu.  However, I can't seem to add a host. When I try adding one, the Zabbix icon is grey and not green to show it Zabbix is up and active. Also, I am stuck in configuring Zabbix as an agent. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please share some more details. Is the agent on the same host as the zabbix server or a separate one? Have you configured the /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent.conf file to point to your zabbix server?

Comment: More details please. Is your zabbix-agent daemon started successfully and listen to default port (10051)?

Comment: I tried installing the agent on the same host as the Zabbix server. I even went ahead as starting the service. However, I keep getting this Error 1053 service did not start in a timely fashion. I tried solving the error, with suggestions on forums but that did not work